# What HTML attribute can I use to get extra information about a p tag?

Tags: html, attributes

I have the following code:

```
<div class="trigger">
    <p>Original Text</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>lorem...</p>
</div>
<script>
    //when p tag inside trigger is clicked content is shown or hidden
</script>
```

I would like to have an extra attribute to get from the p tag to be toggled between the original text.

For example:

```
<p title="Othe text to be toggled">Original text</p>
```

So every time the p tag is clicked it's content change between the original text and the other text.

In this case I don't that title will accomplish its goal, I don't know which html attribute would be the best for this case. Thanks for your time

Comment: Take a look at data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes Then you'd just bind an event listener to whatever you want to mutate your state.

Comment: Thanks @msanford I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @msanford. `data-*` was the perfect solution for me!

```
<div class="trigger">
    <p data-other="Other text">Original Text</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>lorem...</p>
</div>
<script>
    //when p tag inside trigger is clicked content is shown or hidden
</script>
```